# Deploy Artifacts from Ivy to Archiva

Tags: ivy, archiva

Is there anyone have tested how to deploy artifacts within Archiva which security enabled.
I have the following configuration

My ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="archiva"/>
  <resolvers>
    <ibiblio name="archiva" 
             m2compatible="true" 
             root="http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

My build.xml

```
<target name="ivy-init">
  <ivy:settings file="${ivy.settings.dir}/ivysettings.xml"  refid="ivy.classpath">
    <credentials host="localhost" 
         realm="Repository Archiva Managed Internal Repository"
                 username="deploy_user" passwd="deploy_pwd" />
  </ivy:settings>             
</target>

<target name="deploy2Archiva" 
         depends="jar,local-maven-version">

   <ivy:makepom ivyfile="${ivy.file}"
         pomfile="dist/demo-core.pom">
       <mapping conf="compile" scope="compile"/>
       <mapping conf="test" scope="test"/>
   </ivy:makepom>


   <ivy:publish 
    resolver="public"
    pubrevision="${version}"
    overwrite="true"    
    pubdate="${now}"
    status="release"
    forcedeliver="true"
    artifactspattern="${dist.dir}/[artifact].[ext]"/>

</target>
```

My Archiva deploy_user has the 'Repository Manager' Archiva role but I get an unauthorized message.
In fact, the credentials doesn't seem to be into account because if I set the 'Repository Manager' to the guest Archiva user (unauthenticated user), the artifacts are deployed.

Archiva uses the protocol webdav. Have you got experimented credentials with an Ivy webdav resolver?
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: i have a problem, i'm trying to deploy an artifact on archiva internal repository, and everything seems to go ok, in the repositories/internal/ folder i find the .jar .pom and .xml files, but when i try to see the artifact by the ui view it seems the folder is empty... any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

The realm attribute of the credentials element seems to be case-sensitive so you may want to try using realm="Repository Archiva Managed internal Repository" (note the lower case 'i' in 'internal'!)

Answer (score 2):

Was having a lot of trouble with this as well.  Here's the solution:

Turn debug logging on for Ant
Look for a message like this just before the exception:

> [ivy:publish] try to get credentials for: *Repository Archiva Managed internal Repository@domain.com*

You need to add into your ivysettings.xml file credentials that match what it's looking for

```
<credentials
      host="domain.com"
      realm="Repository Archiva Managed internal Repository"
      username="username"
      passwd="password" />
```

The Realm being "Repository Archiva Managed internal Repository" and the host being "domain.com", replaced with whatever values are showing up in your debug output, as well as your correct username and password.

I hope this helps someone!